# What is the simplest way to implement pure css show/hide?

Tags: css, show-hide

I discovered the `<details>` element for html5, and that made me want to determine whether it was possible to implement a simple and reusable show/hide via css alone.

I have created a show/hide mechanism in the past for showing and hiding content by giving two elements relative positioning and one a negative z-index, and then decreasing the z-index of the front element on hover (and increasing the z-index of the back element on hover).

However, that method only works for elements that are in the same location.  Are there other techniques for simulating show/hide on non-overlapping elements?  e.g. a title that causes a section of descriptive text to display.

Trivial example code that I would like to be able to apply a show/hide to:

```
<div id='container'>
<h3 id='show-hide-trigger'>summary</h3>
<p id='show-hide-text'>Paragraph of detail text paragraph Paragraph of detail text paragraph Paragraph of detail text paragraph Paragraph of detail text paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And yes, I do know that jQuery exists.

Comment: Show/hide at what event? Click, hover, ...?

Comment: Either click or hover would work fine, though hovering the trigger area would have to allow moving the hover to the shown area and have it still be shown, though I think that is do-able via just decreasing and increasing z-indexes on hover.  Plus I'm pretty sure there isn't any kind of click trigger in css?

Comment: There actually is: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/pdHDH/

Comment: @{Sime Vidas} Jesus, that's great, good to know.

Comment: See also [Show / hide div on click with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6019845/3075942)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a plethora of options based on the structure (*for modern browsers*).

Have a look at the

1. `selector + selector`  [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)
2. `selector ~ selector`  [general sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)
3. `selector selector`      [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)
4. `selector > selector`  [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

These can be combined with **classes** / **ids** / **pseudo-selectors** like `:hover` etc, and create a big list of options.

here is a small demo i made to showcase them : http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8v9Yz/

Answer (score 3):

Try this using nested divs and targets.
I'm not a CSS guru, so there may be all kinds of flaws with this, but it seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/NmdxC/6/

```
#show {display:none ; }
#hide {display:block;}
#show:target {display: block; }
#hide:target {display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS without the exact code is hard to visualize, but what is wrong with changing the `display` or `visibility` declarations dangling from a `:hover`?

```
a #myelement{display:none;}
a:hover #myelement{display:block;}
```

I problably misunderstood the question...care to add code?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that springs to mind is something like:

```
<a class="blah" href="#">Hello<span>Test</span></a>


a.blah {position:relative}
a.blah span {position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;display:none;}
a.blah:hover span {display:block;}
```

Comment: Just saw your edit... I'm pretty sure you'll need a solution that nests the 'show-hide-text' within the trigger as above, as that's the only way you'll be able to make use of :hover.