# How can I hide/show separetely many different items in html5/css

Tags: css, html, hide, show, onfocus

I have a list of items with a detailed description that I would like to be able to display or hide individually. My html currently looks like

```
<dl class="stuff">
  <dt>title 1</dt>
  <dd> this is the first item
    <pre>
    A hidden by default lengthy description
    that should be copy and pastable
    </pre>
  </dd>
<dt>title 2</dt>
<dd> this is the second item
  <pre>
  Another lengthy description
  </pre>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

The answers to the question [Hide Show content-list with only CSS, no javascript used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731457/hide-show-content-list-with-only-css-no-javascript-used) were quite helpful in getting me started. The closest I got is https://jsfiddle.net/nja66om7/1/ which has all the desired behaviour, but requires creating a new `id` as soon as I add a new item to the list.

My target list would have dozens of items and new items would be added regularly. And although I could generate the html and the css code programmatically and obtain the desired behaviour, I would prefer to keep the css simple. Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour (or a similar one) without creating a new id for each item?

I would prefer not to resort to javascript.