# How to implement "update list after clicking label" in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my webpage, I have a full list of publications.
However, I want to set up a few labels according to different research topics. Then when I click one label, the list of papers is expected to be updated (only the papers related to this topic will be shown, others hidden). How can I implement this? Is there any template on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found a similar question and great answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731457/hide-show-content-list-with-only-css-no-javascript-used

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link, a class could be changed on the list element, and then your CSS could hide/show the papers appropriately.

Comment: could you please explain in more details? I'm new to web design and only know the basics of html. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you can do this with plain HTML. You'll need to learn some basic JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I will start to learn CSS