# Single menu css like facebook alerts?

Tags: html, css

I need to do a menu like this:

[image]

I try to use ul li but I think it is not the way to do that. (i think facebook and even stackoverflow uses a div, maybe).

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>stackoverflow</li>
        <li>superuser</li>
        <li>serverfault</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.list-wrapper,
.items {
   display: inline-block;
}

.list-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1em;
}

.items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}

.items > li:first-child ~ li {
    display: none;
}

.items:hover > li:first-child ~ li {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7rr390k/ 
but my menu is on hover, I want one to click.

my question is: is it a simple ul li menu? or it uses another method?

any good examples to share?

Comment: You would need a simple javascript to add a class, or some CSS directly, and a click listener.

Comment: CSS does not have an onlclick event handler. You have to use Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show / hide div on click with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019845/show-hide-div-on-click-with-css)

Comment: Here is the example of dropdown menu only using css - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you friends, i will check your links and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use if you want only css  :

```
    .items:active > li:first-child ~ li {
    display: block;
}
```

but that will not persist.

So use javascript/Jquery with this :

```
    $( ".items" ).click(function() {
    if (  $( ".onglet" ).css( "display" ) == 'none' ){
        $(".onglet").css("display","block");
    } else {
        $(".onglet").css("display","none" );
    }
});
```

with this html :

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
<ul class="items">
    <li id="title">menu</li>
    <li class="onglet">item 1</li>
    <li class="onglet">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

remove this from your css :

```
    .item:hover > li:first-child ~ li {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: ok let me know if it s okay. it's a simple example I think you can improve it after.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f7rr390k/1/ it is nice! thank you. but it appears that facebook uses a div inside the ul or something... can I put an div there to use an scrollbar?

Comment: Yes it's a question about  architecture of your html. You can do it with ul just limit the maximum heigth of your menu and use the overflow propriety  for the container of your menu.

ps : Facebook use div and no ul because I think they used libraries or framework to support the developpement of the site.

Comment: Yes just add in your css for the .items a max-height  property and a overflow :scroll property.