# how to solve menu list problems

Tags: html

```
<div class="menu-content">
  <div class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/menu-media.png"/></a></div>

</div>
```

```
<ul class="menu-click">
    <a href="#home"><li href="#home">HOME</li></a>
    <a href="#about-us"><li href="#listen">LISTEN</li></a>

    <a href="#contact"><li href="#contact">STUDIO</li></a>

</ul>
```

There are 2 menus in my website when i click on one of them the other open automatically

Comment: Can you post your CSS or Javascript that is opening the menus?

Comment: .menu-media{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
  background:#ada074;
  z-index:1000;
  display:none;
  opacity: 0.53;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 53);
}

.menu-media .menu-content{
  width:280px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  opacity: 0.53;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 53);
}

.menu-media .menu-content .logo {
   color:white;
   font-weight:700;
   font-size:24px;
   width:200px;
   line-height:90px;
   float:left;
   list-style: none;
}

.menu-media .menu-content .icon{
  width:41px;
  height:23px;
  float:right;
  line-height:100px;
}

.menu-click{
  display:none;
}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for a way to show the ul when the div is clicked on? If so, you might look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019845/show-hide-div-on-click-with-css)

Comment: I only need a code to open menu list,to open share buttons menu.

Comment: I suggest you use Javascript to accomplish that. You can use a library like jQuery (Google if you don't know), or [regular old Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp).